# RefineryCMS + Error 'Index was created prior to version 0.6.8. Please delete it, it will be rebuilt automatically.'

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, refinerycms

In my refinery project, I am getting an error message. While creating and editing the pages, I am getting this error on browser screen:

> Index was created prior to version 0.6.8. Please delete it, it will be
>   rebuilt automatically.

I am also getting this:

> Could not find gem 'refinerycms (= 2.0.0) ruby' in
>   git://github.com/refinery/refinerycms.git (at 2-0-stable). Source
>   contains 'refinerycms' at: 2.0.10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to delete `tmp/index` folder this will solve the problem and if you are on windows

add `gem 'acts_as_indexed', :git => 'git://github.com/parndt/acts_as_indexed.git', :branch => 'patch-1' to your gemfile`

visit https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!msg/refinery-cms/KswXQhCkj9E/vUu_PS9aOuAJ for more in depth ans